# Swift How is a setting view implemented

Tags: ios, swift, settings

I was looking through some setting page in apps and saw the setting page in trip advisor

And I wondered how is this implemented is it a stackview of buttons or table view cells? (front end)

[image]

Please note this is not a problem just a question on how is it done or idea behind just to expand my knowledge

Comment: It's a table view with grouped style (instead of plain).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s an tableview cell with more than one section. And tableview style is group.

Comment: Okk just checked it and it’s static and choosing rows depending on the section thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There are two styles of table view. One is plain and the other is grouped. A plain tableView is used while huge data is displayed, i.e. show your contact list. A grouped tableView is used where data is in a group. Here the tableView is grouped. Each group is a section.

The `UITableViewCell` has many styles, custom, left detail, right details, subtitle, etc. Right detail is for some limited string data, where left is title and the answer is on the right of the screen. For example, the Language is a title for a question and the answer is shown on the right, English is the answer. The Autoplay Videos segmented control cell in the tableView is custom.

The left arrow is `UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator` showing that if you tap on the cell or the accessory then you will find more data.